# Can I backup/export settings from SmartThings?

Tags: samsung-smartthings, data-portability

I was wondering if SmartThings supports backing up the settings (or perhaps exporting it in a machine-readable format such as JSON or XML), so that if worst comes to worst, I won't lose my settings and configuration.

I read [this thread](https://community.smartthings.com/t/backup-settings-devices/48296) which suggests that there is no official tool as of May 2016. **Is this still the case? If so, is there any other way to backup or extract the settings from the hub?**

Comment: i guess [this question](https://community.smartthings.com/t/backup-settings-and-restore-in-smartapps/16182) has an answer for you.. just have a look!

Comment: As does [this one](https://community.smartthings.com/t/backup-settings-devices/48296), posted on the same forum a day later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have SmartThings, but do have Google, so here is half an answer.

Comments above [from me](https://community.smartthings.com/t/backup-settings-and-restore-in-smartapps/16182) and [Prashanth](https://community.smartthings.com/t/backup-settings-devices/48296) to SmartThings forum(*) discussions (here, and here) indicate that backup / restore is not available to the casual user.

However, the SmartThings [developer documentation](http://docs.smartthings.com/en/latest/index.html) (which seems quite extensive), give information about overall preferences and settings [here](https://community.smartthings.com/t/backup-settings-devices/48296) and [here](http://docs.smartthings.com/en/latest/smartapp-developers-guide/preferences-and-settings.html).

And [this discussion](https://community.smartthings.com/t/can-i-set-defaults-for-input-values-in-the-preferences-section-of-a-custom-device-type/18664) on the forum appear to show how to programmatically set preferences, which is half of your question answered (and, of course, of little use if you can’t read the preferences to back them up).

I would suggest reading the copious documentation and, if necessary,  asking on the  SmartThiungs forum, to discover how to backup preferences and settings.

---

(*) which might be the best place to ask, rather than here. Great as we are, here on SO, I would always recommend asking in a dedicated forum first, for any subject, before asking here.